# MDT Install Operating System task failed, Return Code = -2147467259 0x80004005

Tags: windows, deployment, mdt

I'm trying to apply an image I captured of a Windows 10 install on a tablet (a Getac) to a VM or another tablet of the same type. In both cases I get the same error every time. There are a few errors that appear in the smsts.log file but I guess the most important one is this one?

```
<![LOG[Could not find CCM install folder. Don't use ccmerrors.dll]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="0" thread="1708" file="string.cpp:1364">
```

Anyone know how I can resolve this? The Task sequence is pretty much unchanged from the Standard Client Task Sequence and I have created a selection profile and media (to boot from USB) also using the defaults. I'm not running any special code that I'm aware of.

I did have problems when I was capturing the image, because of the fall creators update and some miracastview folder missing, but I was able to get around that by copying that folder from the windows.old location as suggested. I'm not sure if this is related.

A more expanded snip of my log file:

```
<![LOG[!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="instruction.cxx:814">
<![LOG[Could not find CCM install folder. Don't use ccmerrors.dll]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="0" thread="1708" file="string.cpp:1364">
<![LOG[Failed to run the action: Install Operating System. 
Unknown error (Error: 000015F8; Source: Unknown)]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="3" thread="1708" file="instruction.cxx:921">
<![LOG[Executing in non SMS standalone mode. Ignoring send a task execution status message request]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="utils.cpp:6496">
<![LOG[Set a global environment variable _SMSTSLastActionRetCode=5624]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="0" thread="1708" file="executionenv.cxx:662">
<![LOG[Set a global environment variable _SMSTSLastActionSucceeded=false]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="0" thread="1708" file="executionenv.cxx:662">
<![LOG[Clear local default environment]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="0" thread="1708" file="executionenv.cxx:801">
<![LOG[Let the parent group (Install) decides whether to continue execution]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="0" thread="1708" file="instruction.cxx:1033">
<![LOG[The execution of the group (Install) has failed and the execution has been aborted. An action failed.
Operation aborted (Error: 80004004; Source: Windows)]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="3" thread="1708" file="instruction.cxx:221">
<![LOG[Could not find CCM install folder. Don't use ccmerrors.dll]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="0" thread="1708" file="string.cpp:1364">
<![LOG[Failed to run the last action: Install Operating System. Execution of task sequence failed.
Unknown error (Error: 000015F8; Source: Unknown)]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="3" thread="1708" file="engine.cxx:249">
<![LOG[Executing in non SMS standalone mode. Ignoring send a task execution status message request]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="utils.cpp:6496">
<![LOG[Task Sequence Engine failed! Code: enExecutionFail]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="3" thread="1708" file="tsmanager.cpp:1285">
<![LOG[****************************************************************************]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="tsmanager.cpp:1313">
<![LOG[Task sequence execution failed with error code 80004005]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="3" thread="1708" file="tsmanager.cpp:1314">
<![LOG[Cleaning Up.]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="tsmanager.cpp:794">
<![LOG[Removing Authenticator]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.022+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="tsmanager.cpp:922">
<![LOG[Cleaning up task sequence folder]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.037+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="utils.cpp:2689">
<![LOG[Unable to delete file E:\_SMSTaskSequence\TSEnv.dat (0x80070005). Continuing.]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.037+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="ccmfile.cpp:1093">
<![LOG[Failed to delete directory 'E:\_SMSTaskSequence']LOG]!><time="15:49:24.037+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="2" thread="1708" file="ccmfile.cpp:1257">
<![LOG[SetNamedSecurityInfo() failed.]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.037+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="3" thread="1708" file="utils.cpp:7413">
<![LOG[SetObjectOwner() failed. 0x80070005.]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.037+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="3" thread="1708" file="utils.cpp:7425">
<![LOG[RemoveFile() failed for E:\_SMSTaskSequence\TSEnv.dat. 0x80070005.]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.037+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="3" thread="1708" file="utils.cpp:7554">
<![LOG[RemoveDirectoryW failed (0x80070091) for E:\_SMSTaskSequence]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.037+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="2" thread="1708" file="utils.cpp:7638">
<![LOG[Deleting volume ID file E:\_SMSTSVolumeID.7159644d-f741-45d5-ab29-0ad8aa4771ca ...]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.037+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="resolvesource.cpp:517">
<![LOG[Deleting volume ID file F:\_SMSTSVolumeID.7159644d-f741-45d5-ab29-0ad8aa4771ca ...]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.037+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="resolvesource.cpp:517">
<![LOG[Deleting volume ID file V:\_SMSTSVolumeID.7159644d-f741-45d5-ab29-0ad8aa4771ca ...]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.037+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="resolvesource.cpp:517">
<![LOG[Successfully unregistered Task Sequencing Environment COM Interface.]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.037+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="environmentlib.cpp:960">
<![LOG[Executing command line: "X:\Deploy\Tools\X64\TsProgressUI.exe" /Unregister]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.037+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="commandline.cpp:828">
<![LOG[==========[ TsProgressUI started in process 1776 ]==========]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.037+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TsProgressUI" context="" type="1" thread="1924" file="winmain.cpp:330">
<![LOG[Unregistering COM classes]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.037+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TsProgressUI" context="" type="1" thread="1924" file="winmain.cpp:204">
<![LOG[Shutdown complete.]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.037+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TsProgressUI" context="" type="1" thread="1924" file="winmain.cpp:512">
<![LOG[Process completed with exit code 0]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.053+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="commandline.cpp:1124">
<![LOG[Successfully unregistered TS Progress UI.]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.053+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="utils.cpp:3263">
<![LOG[RegQueryValueExW is unsuccessful for Software\Microsoft\SMS\Task Sequence, SMSTSEndProgram]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.053+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="2" thread="1708" file="utils.cpp:842">
<![LOG[GetTsRegValue() is unsuccessful. 0x80070002.]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.053+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="2" thread="1708" file="utils.cpp:873">
<![LOG[End program: ]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.053+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="tsmanager.cpp:1060">
<![LOG[Error Task Sequence Manager failed to execute task sequence. Code 0x80004005]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.053+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="3" thread="1708" file="tsmanager.cpp:1064">
<![LOG[Sending error status message]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.053+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="tsmanager.cpp:1065">
<![LOG[In non SMS staqndalone mode.Ignoring SendStatusMessage request]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.053+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="tsmanager.cpp:1892">
<![LOG[Finalizing logs to root of first available drive]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.053+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="tslogging.cpp:1952">
<![LOG[Used smsts.ini to set logging settings.]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.053+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="tslogging.cpp:1457">
<![LOG[Successfully finalized logs to E:\SMSTSLog]LOG]!><time="15:49:24.053+480" date="03-06-2018" component="TSManager" context="" type="1" thread="1708" file="tslogging.cpp:2009">
```

Comment: You should install the [System Center 2012 Toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50012) and use CMTrace to open the log files, makes troubleshooting a lot easier